# Is there a difference between a "child control", a "child window" and a "child window control"?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Or are these terms used to refer to the same thing?

I'm trying to implement some custom buttons showing a bitmap image, into my Win32 app. One tutorial indicates I should be creating child windows using `CreateWindow()`.

However, I have downloaded a bunch of source code from another tutorial on creating "child controls", and no reference is made to `CreateWindow()` (other than the one that creates the main/parent window).

Can anyone help with what a button is classed as? A control or a Window?

Comment: Perhaps the tutorial was discussing windowless controls, http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx

Comment: Hmm could be - I found it near impossible to understand! [http://www.relisoft.com/win32/dialog.html] (sorry - don't know how to put hyperlinks in comments)

Comment: @Michael: I forgot to mention windowless controls, which makes my answer a bit inaccurate - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every control is a window, but not every window is a control.  Controls have a parent and are usually one of the window classes that are appropriate in that context, such as a Button.

Comment: Apparently there *are* window-less controls. So this is not strictly correct.

Comment: Argh. I had an explanation to that effect as an edit, but my internet connection lost it. Have to get the kids to bed before I can retype it.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of Win32, nearly everything on the screen has an underlying HWND associated with it. One of the ways these can be created is via `CreateWindow`. Other methods include loading resources and having the OS built out pre-specified HWNDs via a different mechanism, and I'm sure there are even more.

But yes, to answer your initial question, they're all referring to the same thing: HWNDs that are children of other HWNDs.

Answer (score 0):

According to Charles Petzold's bible, he makes it very clear that every thing is a window, from child controls to windows itself. He asserts that is because a call to CreateWindow using a handle which is a pointer to the window structure. This is a holdover from the pre Win 3 days.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.